# GDB print command to evaluate boolean expressions?

Tags: c++, c, boolean, gdb, expression

In gdb I can print variables but when I've complicated if statement in the code like [this](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/master/llvm/lib/Transforms/Vectorize/LoopVectorize.cpp#L1585) one in LLVM loop vectorizer. What I want is to see when `EnableVPlanNativePath` evaluates to true. It's not nullptr in this case. It's instance of [cl::opt](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1cl_1_1opt.html).

So in gdb I've tried `p EnableVPlanNativePath && true` which gives me error `No symbol "operator&&" in current context.` I also tried different format outputs like `p/u EnableVPlanNativePath && true` but I get the same result as earlier. Is this possible without modifying the source code and making intermediate boolean variable which I can then print for sure.

In this case EnableVPlanNativePath should evaluate to true and VPlanBuildStressTest to false. I noticed there is getValue() function which returns the value correctly:

```
(gdb) p EnableVPlanNativePath.getValue()
$25 = (bool &) @0x7fffef42b6a8: true
(gdb) p VPlanBuildStressTest.getValue()
$26 = (bool &) @0x7fffef42ca28: false
```

I'm assuming in LLVM source code there is somewhere operator bool() override but cannot find it.

How to evaluate statement to boolean without modifying the source code?
I'm doing the same thing in Python with `bool(some-boolean-expression)`.

Comment: Have you tried `p (int)EnableVPlanNativePath `?

Comment: Tried but both options print same interger number. Updated original question to include more information.